# How to extract a value from a hash

Tags: ruby, hashmap

I have a parsed JSON file that contains a Hash:

```
{
  "user1" : {
    "about_you" : "jjhj",
    "age" : 18,
    "email" : 18
   },
  "user2" : {
    "about_you" : "jjhj",
    "age" : 18,
    "email" : 18
   },
  "user3" : {
    "about_you" : "jjhj",
    "age" : 18,
    "email" : 18
   }
}
```

I'm trying to loop and get all the email values and write them to a CSV file.

At the moment I'm trying to read the email, and tried a few variations but this is the closest I got, but it doesn't read the value, it just shows blank.

```
data_hash = JSON.parse(File.read('user.json'))

data_hash.keys.each do |user|
  puts user['email']
end
```

Comment: Really your question is about extracting a value from a Hash. That the data starts out as JSON doesn't matter, because when you read and parse it, it's no longer JSON, it's a hash. So, when asking, be sure to reduce the problem, question and tags, to the actual things involved. Anything more than that only causes confusion. Please see "[ask]", "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)" and all their linked pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `keys` method [returns an array of the key names](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Hash.html#method-i-keys); it doesn't return the values.

Given these inputs:

```
json = '{"user1":{"about_you":"jjhj","age":18,"email":18},"user2":{"about_you":"jjhj","age":18,"email":18},"user3":{"about_you":"jjhj","age":18,"email":18}}'
data_hash = JSON.parse(json)
```

Try just iterating over the hash's keys and values:

```
data_hash.each { |k,v| puts v['email'] }
```

Or if you prefer:

```
data_hash.each do |k,v|
  puts v['email']
end
```

Each returns:

```
18
18
18
```

Comment: what if i wanted to check if the email field exists? i tried if v['email'] but that doesn't get me anywhere, also tried working with .key? but thats a dead end. some of the objects don't contain email, so wanted to put a check before printing them?

Comment: `puts v['email'] if v.key?('email')`

Answer (score 1):

If you only need the email data then you can just use [`map`](https://apidock.com/ruby/Array/map):

```
data_hash = JSON.parse(File.read('user.json'))
data_hash.values.map{|x| x[:email]}
```